# Having problem creating Sql procedure in phpmyadmin

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin

Following is my SQL procedure. I want to update user's profile details.

```
DELIMITER // 
CREATE PROCEDURE `UserTable_Update`(
IN `Id` INT(11),
IN `Name` VARCHAR(60),
IN `Mobile` INT(15),
IN `Email` VARCHAR(80),
IN `Address` LONGTEXT,
IN `Address2` VARCHAR(200),
IN `Dob` VARCHAR(10),
IN `Prefered` INT(11),
IN `Marriage_status` INT(1),
IN `Marriage_date` VARCHAR(10),
IN PASSWORD VARCHAR(150),
IN Latitude VARCHAR(60),
IN Longitude VARCHAR(60),
IN Latitude2 INT(60),
IN Longitude2 INT(60)
) NOT DETERMINISTIC CONTAINS SQL SQL SECURITY DEFINER
BEGIN
UPDATE
    USER
SET name= NAME,
    mobile = Mobile,
    email = Email,
    address = Address,
    address2 = Address2,
    dob = Dob,
    prefered = Prefered,
    marriage_status = Marriage_status,
    marriage_date = Marriage_date,
    latitude = Latitude,
    longitude = Longitude,
    latitude2 = Latitude2,
    longitude2 = Longitude2
    WHERE
    user_id = Id
    END //
```

I am getting following error.

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB 
server version for the right syntax to use near 'END' at line 37
```

What am I doing wrong?? I never used procedures before so, please help out

Comment: Semicolon after UPDATE query (after `user_id = Id`) before END statement is lost.

Comment: how about `user_id = Id;
    END;` ??? Answer to yourself - why do you do `delimiter`?

Comment: lol. thanks. @Akina

Comment: Yeah, got it, @T.S. Actually i was using if else in procedure but couldn't make it work so decided to write something simple first. :D

Comment: @T.S. is right - single-queried procedure do not need in BEGIN-END block and delimiter reassing. If your SP is slightly more complex (contains IF), then it is possible that it can be converted to single-query form without effectiveness loss nevertheless...

Comment: PS. Why you define your SP as `NOT DETERMINISTIC`? it is deterministic, it returns nothing always :-) ...